# Prefix Error for Table and Server Call

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update, procedure, prefix

I'm getting the following error(s)

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Procedure lp_..._data, Line 153
The object name 'abcDBProd.Intermediate.dbo.upld_data' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Procedure lp_..._Tables, Line 520
The object name 'ABCDBPROD.Intermediate.dbo.UPLD_data' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

If I understand correctly the purpose/meaning of the error that I can't have more then 2 prefixes prior to the table name. In the first statement i'm using the name of the Server itself and in the second case the LinkedServer name. The confusion I've got is that i have many tables on this server/databse and they are all connected the same and none of them are causing this error. but this one is.

What do I do? Is it a permission issue or security issue? I'm not sure where to look.

Does it matter if the command calling the table, truncates, inserts or updates the data? Are there restrictions like I can't truncate but I can insert? Why does it work in some cases but not in others?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server supports four-part naming:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx.  On the other hand, I would always use readable table aliases.

Comment: Can you share the actual query where you are trying to reference this. Also keep in mind that 4 part naming is using a linked server. My guess is you have a table with a period in the name but that is just a guess.

Comment: I'll review but i don't see any tables with periods. All are pretty similar upld_name there are some select into, insert into, truncates, drops, uplds etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked tables are not allowed in some contexts, such as `DROP TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`.  If you use a name that includes the server name, then you will get this error.

For instance, this is not allowed:

```
drop table abcDBProd.Intermediate.dbo.upld_data;
```

You may be able to work around this with `openquery()`.

Comment: There are several insert into's in the code not causing errors/issues except this one - what about truncate table?

Comment: delete from `ABCDBPROD.Intermediate.dbo.UPLD_data` works